# So, I tried t install git-all and it removed various gnome packages in my system, I don't really know the reason. How can I overcome this?

Tags: debian, gnome, git

I was installing git-all in my system and did it without reading the confirmation of packages that it would be messing with, and when I returned my graphical interface was simply gone...

Don't know why it removed those gnome packages but it did, so what happened and how can I overcome this?

Also is it necessary for me to install git-all, can I install only git? What is the difference between these two packages?

I think its worth mentioning that I'm using debian 10 'buster' and I do have some non-free firmware since my wireless card required it, although I don't think that this has nothing to do with my problem...

Thanks for the help in advance, I'm 17 years old completely new to this technical world, can't really code anything but a "hello world".

I previously asked about this in stack overflow but [kaylum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3003365/kaylum) explained to me that stack overflow is destined only to programming related questions, so I wanted to express my gratitude to him for showing me these site, so... Thanks dude!

I did revise the help page from this site, stack overflow and super user, and I think it's plausible for me to ask here, even so if it's not fitting for this site as well, do let me know...

Right below here is the output of `sudo apt install git-all`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  accountsservice apg appstream apt-config-icons argyll argyll-ref bolt colord-data cracklib-runtime desktop-file-utils dnsmasq-base exfat-fuse
  exfat-utils fwupd fwupd-amd64-signed gdisk gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-clutter-gst-3.0 gir1.2-dazzle-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3
  gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-grilo-0.3 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-mediaart-2.0 gir1.2-mutter-3 gir1.2-nm-1.0
  gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gnome-control-center-data gnome-session-bin
  gnome-session-common gnome-shell-common gnome-software-common gvfs-common gvfs-libs hyphen-en-us javascript-common libaccountsservice0
  libappstream-glib8 libappstream4 libatasmart4 libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-part2
  libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libcdio-cdda2 libcdio-paranoia2 libcolord-gtk1 libcolorhug2 libcrack2 libfwupd2 libgcab-1.0-0
  libgdm1 libgnome-menu-3-0 libibus-1.0-5 libmusicbrainz5-2 libmusicbrainz5cc2v5 libndp0 libnfs12 libnm0 libnma0 libnss-myhostname libntfs-3g883
  libparted-fs-resize0 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libreoffice-help-common libreoffice-help-en-us
  libsmbios-c2 libteamdctl0 libtss2-esys0 libtss2-udev libudisks2-0 libvolume-key1 libxmlb1 mobile-broadband-provider-info mousetweaks mythes-en-us
  nautilus-data node-normalize.css ntfs-3g python3-distro-info python3-software-properties realmd software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  switcheroo-control tpm2-abrmd tpm2-tools unattended-upgrades xwayland
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-data apache2-utils cvs cvsps elpa-async elpa-dash elpa-ghub elpa-git-commit elpa-graphql elpa-let-alist elpa-magit
  elpa-magit-popup elpa-treepy elpa-with-editor emacs emacs-bin-common emacs-common emacs-el emacs-gtk exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light
  git git-cvs git-daemon-run git-doc git-el git-email git-gui git-man git-mediawiki git-svn gitk gitweb guile-2.2-libs imagemagick-6-common
  initscripts insserv install-info libalgorithm-c3-perl libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl
  libclass-c3-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-factory-util-perl libclass-inspector-perl
  libclass-method-modifiers-perl libclass-singleton-perl libclass-xsaccessor-perl libcommon-sense-perl libdata-optlist-perl
  libdatetime-format-builder-perl libdatetime-format-iso8601-perl libdatetime-format-strptime-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl
  libdatetime-timezone-perl libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbi-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-caller-perl libdevel-lexalias-perl
  libdevel-stacktrace-perl libdigest-bubblebabble-perl libdigest-hmac-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl libemail-valid-perl liberror-perl
  libeval-closure-perl libexception-class-perl libfcgi-perl libfile-sharedir-perl libgc1c2 libgnutls-dane0 libgsasl7 libheif1 libjson-perl
  libjson-xs-perl libkyotocabinet16v5 liblqr-1-0 liblzo2-2 libm17n-0 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmailutils5 libmediawiki-api-perl
  libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libmro-compat-perl libnamespace-autoclean-perl libnamespace-clean-perl libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-dns-sec-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libnet-libidn-perl libntlm0 libotf0 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl
  libpadwalker-perl libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl libparams-validate-perl libparams-validationcompiler-perl libreadonly-perl
  libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl librole-tiny-perl libserf-1-1 libspecio-perl libsub-exporter-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl
  libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl libsub-name-perl libsub-quote-perl libsvn-perl libsvn1 libtcl8.6 libterm-readkey-perl libtk8.6
  libtypes-serialiser-perl libunbound8 libutf8proc2 libvariable-magic-perl libyaml-libyaml-perl libyaml-perl m17n-db mailutils mailutils-common
  runit runit-helper runit-sysv startpar sysuser-helper sysv-rc sysvinit-core tcl tcl8.6 tk tk8.6
Suggested packages:
  apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom mksh rcs emacs-common-non-dfsg exim4-doc-html | exim4-doc-info eximon4 spf-tools-perl
  swaks meld mediawiki subversion bootchart2 libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libsql-statement-perl m17n-docs
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libscalar-number-perl libtest-fatal-perl libyaml-shell-perl gawk mailutils-mh mailutils-doc bootlogd tcl-tclreadline
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  chrome-gnome-shell colord dbus-user-session gdm3 gnome gnome-color-manager gnome-control-center gnome-core gnome-disk-utility gnome-music
  gnome-session gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-extensions gnome-software gnome-sushi gnome-tweaks gstreamer1.0-packagekit gvfs
  gvfs-backends gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse libpam-systemd nautilus nautilus-extension-brasero network-manager network-manager-gnome packagekit
  packagekit-tools policykit-1 rtkit systemd-sysv task-gnome-desktop udisks2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-data apache2-utils cvs cvsps elpa-async elpa-dash elpa-ghub elpa-git-commit elpa-graphql elpa-let-alist elpa-magit
  elpa-magit-popup elpa-treepy elpa-with-editor emacs emacs-bin-common emacs-common emacs-el emacs-gtk exim4-base exim4-config exim4-daemon-light
  git git-all git-cvs git-daemon-run git-doc git-el git-email git-gui git-man git-mediawiki git-svn gitk gitweb guile-2.2-libs imagemagick-6-common
  initscripts insserv install-info libalgorithm-c3-perl libb-hooks-endofscope-perl libb-hooks-op-check-perl libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl
  libclass-c3-perl libclass-c3-xs-perl libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-factory-util-perl libclass-inspector-perl
  libclass-method-modifiers-perl libclass-singleton-perl libclass-xsaccessor-perl libcommon-sense-perl libdata-optlist-perl
  libdatetime-format-builder-perl libdatetime-format-iso8601-perl libdatetime-format-strptime-perl libdatetime-locale-perl libdatetime-perl
  libdatetime-timezone-perl libdbd-sqlite3-perl libdbi-perl libdevel-callchecker-perl libdevel-caller-perl libdevel-lexalias-perl
  libdevel-stacktrace-perl libdigest-bubblebabble-perl libdigest-hmac-perl libdynaloader-functions-perl libemail-valid-perl liberror-perl
  libeval-closure-perl libexception-class-perl libfcgi-perl libfile-sharedir-perl libgc1c2 libgnutls-dane0 libgsasl7 libheif1 libjson-perl
  libjson-xs-perl libkyotocabinet16v5 liblqr-1-0 liblzo2-2 libm17n-0 libmagickcore-6.q16-6 libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmailutils5 libmediawiki-api-perl
  libmodule-implementation-perl libmodule-runtime-perl libmro-compat-perl libnamespace-autoclean-perl libnamespace-clean-perl libnet-dns-perl
  libnet-dns-sec-perl libnet-domain-tld-perl libnet-ip-perl libnet-libidn-perl libntlm0 libotf0 libpackage-stash-perl libpackage-stash-xs-perl
  libpadwalker-perl libparams-classify-perl libparams-util-perl libparams-validate-perl libparams-validationcompiler-perl libreadonly-perl
  libref-util-perl libref-util-xs-perl librole-tiny-perl libserf-1-1 libspecio-perl libsub-exporter-perl libsub-exporter-progressive-perl
  libsub-identify-perl libsub-install-perl libsub-name-perl libsub-quote-perl libsvn-perl libsvn1 libtcl8.6 libterm-readkey-perl libtk8.6
  libtypes-serialiser-perl libunbound8 libutf8proc2 libvariable-magic-perl libyaml-libyaml-perl libyaml-perl m17n-db mailutils mailutils-common
  runit runit-helper runit-sysv startpar sysuser-helper sysv-rc sysvinit-core tcl tcl8.6 tk tk8.6
0 upgraded, 147 newly installed, 34 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 80.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 261 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

**EDIT: **
Ok, I used the --dry-run switch as ajgringo619 suggested me, and found out while reading it slower that it wasn't removing only the gnome packages, but packages like nautilus, network-manager... and many others that I don't even know the purpose, saying that those packages are no longer required, even though I think network-manager is required when you're downloading something.

As to what I was doing before this: Nothing, I mean, the first time I ran `sudo apt install git-all -y` I broke my system and reinstalled it because I'm not knowledgeable enough to repair it on my on, and after that, before installing anything, any non-free firmware I ran the same command and broke it for the second time, after reinstalling it the second time I didn't avoided the `git-all` package, installed vscode, zeal, removed games that came with the system, changed background and when I thought about installing `git-all` I removed the `-y` thing and actually read the output. Here I am now, asking for help.

This are the packages that it wants to remove:

```
Remv chrome-gnome-shell [10.1-5]
Remv gnome [1:3.30+1]
Remv task-gnome-desktop [3.53]
Remv gnome-core [1:3.30+1]
Remv gnome-control-center [1:3.30.3-2~deb10u1]
Remv gnome-color-manager [3.30.0-2]
Remv colord [1.4.3-4]
Remv network-manager-gnome [1.8.20-1.1]
Remv dbus-user-session [1.12.20-0+deb10u1]
Remv gdm3 [3.30.2-3]
Remv gnome-disk-utility [3.30.2-3]
Remv gnome-music [3.30.2-1]
Remv gnome-session [3.30.1-2]
Remv gnome-tweaks [3.30.2-1]
Remv gnome-shell-extensions [3.30.1-1]
Remv gnome-settings-daemon [3.30.2-3] [gnome-shell:amd64 ]
Remv gnome-shell [3.30.2-11~deb10u2]
Remv gnome-software [3.30.6-5]
Remv gnome-sushi [3.30.0-2]
Remv gstreamer1.0-packagekit [1.1.12-5]
Remv gvfs-backends [1.38.1-5]
Remv nautilus [3.30.5-2]
Remv gvfs [1.38.1-5] [gvfs-fuse:amd64 nautilus-extension-brasero:amd64 ]
Remv gvfs-daemons [1.38.1-5] [gvfs-fuse:amd64 nautilus-extension-brasero:amd64 ]
Remv gvfs-fuse [1.38.1-5] [nautilus-extension-brasero:amd64 ]
Remv udisks2 [2.8.1-4] [nautilus-extension-brasero:amd64 ]
Remv rtkit [0.11-6] [nautilus-extension-brasero:amd64 ]
Remv policykit-1 [0.105-25] [network-manager:amd64 packagekit:amd64 nautilus-extension-brasero:amd64 ]
Remv libpam-systemd [241-7~deb10u4] [network-manager:amd64 packagekit:amd64 nautilus-extension-brasero:amd64 ]
Remv nautilus-extension-brasero [3.12.2-5] [network-manager:amd64 packagekit:amd64 ]
Remv network-manager [1.14.6-2+deb10u1] [packagekit:amd64 ]
Remv packagekit-tools [1.1.12-5] [packagekit:amd64 ]
Remv packagekit [1.1.12-5]
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that the list of packages to autoremove was caused by your apt command. What were you doing before this? In the future, if you're not sure about what an apt command is going to do, add the `--dry-run` switch. This will tell you *exactly* what is going to happen, but won't actually do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to use the `git` tool, you do not need to install `git-all`. You can look the description of the packages by running `apt-cache show git` and `apt-cache show git-all`, as well as the packages they install, read the materials they link to, and then decide.

The package `git-all` recommends alternatively `git-daemon-run` or `git-daemon-sysvinit`, but `apt` automatically chooses `git-daemon-run` for some reason:

```
$ apt depends git-all
git-all
  Залежності (Depends): git (>> 1:2.20.1)
  Залежності (Depends): git (<< 1:2.20.1-.)
  Залежності (Depends): git-doc
  Залежності (Depends): git-el
  Залежності (Depends): git-cvs
  Залежності (Depends): git-mediawiki
  Залежності (Depends): git-svn
  Залежності (Depends): git-email
  Залежності (Depends): git-gui
  Залежності (Depends): gitk
  Залежності (Depends): gitweb
 |Рекомендує (Recommends): git-daemon-run
  Рекомендує (Recommends): git-daemon-sysvinit
```

According to the package description, which you can lookup with `apt show git-daemon-run` (emphasis mine):

> git-daemon, as provided by the git package, is a simple server for
> git  repositories, ideally suited for read-only updates, i.e. pulling
> from git  repositories through the network.  This package provides a
> runit service  for running git-daemon permanently.  **This
> configuration is simpler and  more reliable than git-daemon-sysvinit,
> at a cost of being less  familiar for administrators accustomed to
> sysvinit.**

`git-daemon-run` depends on `runit`, which recommends alternatively `runit-sysv`, `runit-init`, or `runit-systemd`. `apt` chooses `runit-sysv` for some reason. `runit-sysv` depends on `sysvinit-core`. This and `runit-init` conflict with `systemd-sysv`, which is already installed by default on Debian:

```
$ apt depends sysvinit-core runit-init --installed
sysvinit-core
  Залежності (Depends): debianutils (>= 4)
  Залежності (Depends): sysvinit-utils (>= 2.86.ds1-66)
 |Залежності (Depends): debconf (>= 0.5)
    cdebconf
    debconf
  Залежності (Depends): libc6 (>= 2.15)
  Залежності (Depends): libselinux1 (>= 1.32)
  Залежності (Depends): libsepol1 (>= 2.4)
  Конфлікти (Conflicts): systemd-sysv
  Заміняє (Replaces): systemd-sysv
runit-init
  Залежності (Depends): libc6 (>= 2.4)
  Конфлікти (Conflicts): systemd-sysv
  Заміняє (Replaces): systemd-sysv
```

So, to resolve your issue, you have to instruct `apt` to keep `systemd-sysv` when installing `git-all`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git-all systemd-sysv
```

This time `apt` will choose `runit-systemd` and no packages should be removed.

Answer (score 3):

`git-all` recommends `git-daemon-run`, and that depends on `runit`, which conflicts with systemd, or rather `systemd-sysv`. This ends up causing a conflict with GNOME, and `apt` chooses to remove the conflicting packages.

To avoid this, there are two solutions:

- install `git-all` without the recommended packages:

  ```
  sudo apt install --no-install-recommends git-all
  ```
- avoid installing `git-all`, and only install the packages you need:

  ```
  sudo apt install git
  ```

Comment: Your help was just as useful, but I had a problem because I'm still learning and when you said "Install the packages you need", because I don't really know what I'll need to use, but you were just as helpful, thanks

Comment: No worries; I listed the only package you’re likely to need in the command, `sudo apt install git` ;-).

Comment: Well, I'll try to use the git package only, and if I'm unable to do anything I'll google what packages are necessary to do whatever it is that I'm trying to do. Thanks again for your time

Comment: The package descriptions should help you determine which ones will be useful: `apt show git` etc. You can also use `apt search` to find packages matching certain words.